# "in the field" or "on the land"

Tags: prepositions

> The farmer found a furrow in the land.
>
> The dog observed a hole in the land.
>
> The dog sniffed a hole in the field.

Not sure if both are ok. To me, both are grammatical, but I am not sure if it's the case and how to tell if it's grammatical or not.

Comment: It is more idiomatic to say "in the ground" rather than "in the land."

Comment: They are all _grammatical_, but that doesn't mean that a native speaker would use them! See Steve's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t ever heard “in the land” used this way. “In the field” or “in the ground” are common ways of saying this.

“Land” in often used to convey ownership, either private as in “this is my land” or shared as in “this land is our land. The famous Woody Guthrie song illustrates the latter sense: “This land is your land, this land is my land, . . . this land was made for you and me.”

Comment: Just to add to this, a field is normally cultivated or farmed land

Answer (score 0):

Generally, "the land" is an extremely vague and general term. You find it in phrases like "America is truly the land of opportunity." or, "Under the rule of the usurper, a spirit of rebellion swept the land." As such, "a hole in the land" is too specific to be used.

There are other, more specific uses. "I found gold on the land I purchased" would work, where "the land I purchased" is a specific plot of land. But without a qualifier, either direct or implicit in earlier description, "the land" is a very indistinct entity, and would be matched with an equally non-specific description.

There is an intermediate category, which is both vague and specific at the same time. "The land west of the Rockies (in the US)" refers to a specific area of the US, but the character of the included territory varies wildly, from the Mojave Desert to the Oregon rainforest so that a sentence like "The land west of the Rockies is a bleak desert" can be either true or false depending on context. A speaker at the southern end of the Rockies could use the phrase to refer to the area to the west, implicitly restricting it to that area.